# How to remove dependent rows instead of set Null in one-to-many Relation?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I Have two simple Models. **Person** and **BankAccount**.

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public IList<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public IList<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }
    }


    public class BankAccount
    {
        public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

in the database, i have three rows. 
 
[image]

now, i want to update **value** column of This person. This is my code:

```
var bankAccounts = new List<BankAccount>
{
    new BankAccount {Value = 100},
    new BankAccount {Value = 200},
    new BankAccount {Value = 300},
};

var person = context.People
                    .Include(p => p.BankAccounts)
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.PersonId.Equals(12));

person.BankAccounts = bankAccounts;

context.SaveChanges();
```

after i run my code, i get bellow result: 
[image]

**how i can delete null rows? i want bellow result:** 


[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are detaching old BankAccounts and attach new BankAccounts

first add `public int PersonId { get; set; }` to BankAccount class

then:

```
person.BankAccounts.ToList().AddRange(bankAccounts);

context.SaveChanges();
```